# How to concatenate two files in a loop?

Tags: directory, cat

I have two files that I want to concatenate in one new file, but I want to do it by using a loop because I have different directories (a, b, c, g and z) with same 2 files.
My loop is:

```
for i in a b c g z
do
    (cd $i/; for i in File_*_best3.txt *_new3.txt; do cat $i > combined.txt; done)
done
```

But my result is a `combined.txt` file exactly the same as my second input file, so my cat is not working properly. What is the issue here?

Comment: Don't use the same variable for the loop and inside the loop to mean different things.  `for $i in` and your `cat $i` are logically meaning different things.  maybe use `d` for the directories, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that each time `cat` is executed, the output file is truncated (emptied). This is because you use `>` for redirection.

Alternative:

```
for d in a b c g z
do
    (cd "$d"; rm -f combined.txt; for i in File_*_best3.txt *_new3.txt; do cat "$i" >>combined.txt; done)
done
```

or

```
for d in a b c g z
do
    (cd "$d" && cat File_*_best3.txt *_new3.txt >combined.txt)
done
```

I'm assuming that `File_*_best3.txt` and `*_new3.txt` only matches one filename each.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without `cd`:

```
for d in a b c g z; do
    cat $d/{File_*_best3.txt,*_new3.txt} >$d/combined.txt
done
```

Comment: Did not work, I got some errors like -  cat: 'a/{File_*_best3.txt,': No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe your shell can handle that!?  I've used ```bash```. Probably "```cat $d/File_*_best3.txt  $d/*_new3.txt```" would work for you.